# Check windows date format using access vba

Tags: vba, windows, date, ms-access, format

Is there any piece of vba code to check for windows desktop format in Access?
I've requirement if windows date format is not English(United states) then access must exit. If date format is English(United Kingdom) then it should open.

Please support.

Comment: _English(United states)_ and _English(United Kingdom)_ are different, so your question doesn't make sense. So rephrase, please.

Comment: @Gustav Huh? It must exit if it's English (United States) and it must open if it's English (United kingdom). That just leaves undefined behavior if it's neither, but does make some sense.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: That's what I thought. But read again: _not_ English(US) which could be _is English(UK) => Exit_. But then: _is English(UK) => Open_.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. Well, the logic for getting the date format remains constant. What to do after you got it is the only thing that changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get the current date format.

Personally, I look it up in the registry using WScript.Shell:

```
Dim strDateFormat As String
strDateFormat = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKCU\Control Panel\International\sShortDate")
```

This returns the date format that Access uses, for example `dd/MM/yyyy` for UK.

You can also test date formats by testing specific dates:

```
If Format(#01/02/1911#, "Short Date") <> "02/01/1911" Then 'Wrong format  
'VBA always uses mm/dd/yyyy internally, you can also use DateSerial(2011,01,02)
```

There's also a second date format, the *Long Date* format, but that's not used by Access internally, so I assume you're not interested in that one.

Comment: Hi erik, Thanks. Let me work out your suggestion and post back.

Comment: But Eric, "Short Date" could be anything. I know, most will never tough it, just leave the default, but still.

Comment: Hi Erik, Many thanks. It just worked as i expected and it's cool ☺

Comment: @Gustav I'm testing if a hard-coded date returns the desired string after formatting it to a short date. If it does, I know the system short date format is the desired short date format. The system short date format is equal to the one defined in the registry. In Excel you can override it, in Access you can't.

Comment: Access adapts the format from _Windows_ - which you easily can change to, say, _yyyy-mm-dd_.

Comment: Yes, but as I understand the question, the OP wants to look up the windows date format. `#01/02/1911#` is a date literal for the 2nd of January 2011, that won't change, so we can test if the Windows date format is the desired format by using `Format` and checking if it returns the expected string.